# Not able to connect to mongodb replica set running in docker in different machine

Tags: mongodb, docker, database-replication

I am using mongo server in which there are three dockers that are running and another one which maps all the three mongo dockers and creates replica from them.
Config for same is:

```
mongo1:
  build: mongodb/
  hostname: mongo1
  expose:
    - "27017"
  ports:
    - "ip:27017:27017"
  # links:
  #   - mongo2:mongo2
  #   - mongo3:mongo3
  restart: always
  volumes:
    - ./data/mongodb/mongo1:/data/db
  entrypoint: [ "/usr/bin/mongod", "--replSet=rs", "--noauth",  "--rest", "--httpinterface", "--dbpath", "/data/db","--port","27017","--bind_ip","0.0.0.0" ]
  mem_limit: 1024m


mongo2:
   build: mongodb/
   hostname: mongo2
   expose:
     - "27018"
   ports:
    - "ip:27018:27017"
   restart: always
   volumes:
     - ./data/mongodb/mongo2:/data/db
   entrypoint: [ "/usr/bin/mongod", "--replSet=rs", "--rest", "--httpinterface", "--dbpath", "/data/db","--port","27017","--bind_ip","0.0.0.0" ]
   #  mem_limit: 512m

mongo3:
    build: mongodb/
    hostname: mongo3
    expose:
     - "27019"
    ports:
     - "ip:27019:27017"
    restart: always 
    volumes:
     - ./data/mongodb/mongo3:/data/db
    entrypoint: [ "/usr/bin/mongod", "--replSet=rs", "--rest", "--httpinterface", "--dbpath", "/data/db","--port","27017","--bind_ip","0.0.0.0" ]
    # mem_limit: 512m
```

where ip is my server ip.
And the setup file which set replica is:

```
mongosetup:
    build: mongodb/ 
    links:
     - mongo1:mongo1 
     - mongo2:mongo2
     - mongo3:mongo3
    volumes:
     - ./mongodb/scripts:/scripts
    restart: always
    entrypoint: [ "bash", "/scripts/mongosetup.sh" ]
    mem_limit: 256m
```

Script mongosetup.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
MONGODB1=`ping -c 1 mongo1 | head -1  | cut -d "(" -f 2 | cut -d ")" -f 1`
MONGODB2=`ping -c 1 mongo2 | head -1  | cut -d "(" -f 2 | cut -d ")" -f 1`
MONGODB3=`ping -c 1 mongo3 | head -1  | cut -d "(" -f 2 | cut -d ")" -f 1`

echo SETUP.sh time now: `date +"%T" `
mongo --host ${MONGODB1}:27017 <<
   var cfg = {
        "_id": "rs",
        "version": 1,
        "members": [
            {
                "_id": 0,
                "host": "${MONGODB1}:27017",
                "priority": 2
            },
            {
                "_id": 1,
                "host": "${MONGODB2}:27018",
                "priority": 0
            },
            {
                "_id": 2,
                "host": "${MONGODB3}:27019",
                "priority": 0
            }
        ]
    };
    rs.initiate(cfg, { force: true });
    rs.reconfig(cfg, { force: true });
    db.getMongo().setReadPref('nearest');
```

Now when I am trying to connect from the test server (which have all these dockers) its working. Connection url for same from my node js server:

```
var uri = "mongodb://ip:27017,ip:27018,ip:27019/stagedb/?replicaSet=rs";
mongoose.connect(uri);
```

where ip is my test server ip.

Also I tried to connect from mongo shell as

```
mongo --host rs/ip:27017,ip:27018,ip:27019 stagedb
```

But when trying to connect test server mongo from remote server with same connection string as above its throwing error:

> Database connection error MongoError: failed to connect to server [172.17.0.5:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connection 71 to 172.17.0.5:27017 timed out]

The IP 172.17.0.5 is of docker while I am trying to connect to test server ip.

Also from local mongo shell its giving error as:

> 2017-06-12T14:22:55.531+0530 W NETWORK  Failed to connect to 172.17.0.2:27017 after 5000 milliseconds, giving up.
>   2017-06-12T14:23:00.535+0530 W NETWORK  Failed to connect to 172.17.0.5:27017 after 5000 milliseconds, giving up.
>   2017-06-12T14:23:05.495+0530 W NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitorWatcher] Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3:27017 after 5000 milliseconds, giving up.
>   2017-06-12T14:23:05.498+0530 E QUERY    Error: connect failed to replica set rs/test.elanic.co:27017,test.elanic.co:27018,test.elanic.co:27019
>       at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:181:14)
>       at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:181
>   exception: connect failed

Anyone have idea why its trying to map directly to docker ip or any other issue.

Comment: firewall or bind address issues ? try to connect using netcat " nc -v 172.17.0.5 27017"

Comment: Can you try with `0.0.0.0` instead of `172.17.0.5`. I had similar issues with mysql. You can try pinging or `traceroute 172.17.0.5`, you will see packet drops as `172.17.0.5` will be treating as a public ip address than private.

Comment: @ApriOri so If I use single docker server : mongo --host ip:27018 stagedb it works.                                                          But when i use mongo --host rs/ip:27017,ip:27018,ip:27019 stagedb Its not working so issue cannot be with firewall.For netcat from remote server I got : nc -v 172.17.0.5 27017: forward host lookup failed: Unknown host.

Comment: @harshavmb: Pinging ip 172.17.0.5 is treated as public. but how I can use 0.0.0.0 as from remote server I know only test server and 172.17.0.5 is docker ip inside test server.Also while creating docker I am binding ip with 0.0.0.0 so my docker port mapping is : 27018/tcp, 0.0.0.0:27018->27017/tcp.

Comment: Okies. I'm very pristine when it comes to docker. Just thought I'll tell my crappy workaround. I got your question, I'm sorry I don't have an answer. Please keep posted about the fix. Thanks